# How to get the entire string reported by __LINE__

Tags: c, shell

Is it possible to get the entire string on line reported through **LINE** macro.
Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG(lvl) pLog(lvl, __LINE__, __FILE__)

pLog(const char *str, int line, const char *file)
{
    printf("Line [%u]: File [%s]", line, file);
}

int main ()
{
    LOG("Hello"
            "world");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is: Line [13]: File [macro.c]

Now in a large code base i want to search this file and print the string "Hello world" present at line reported (in this case it is 13)

One way i was thinking is to search for this file first generate the output file with gcc -E do grep for pLog and save their string then grep for LOG in actual code file and save line number match the line number with the line number present in result and then do matching of index and print the string.

As string can be distributed across multiple lines (as in code Hello is in one line and world is in another line) so also need to take care of that.

Is there anyother best and fast way of doing it or gcc provide some option to convert back line and file to actual code

Comment: If you are frequently splitting strings across multiple lines, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: In your example you can simply output the value of `str` in the printf.

Comment: uhm, why not `printf("Line [%u]: File [%s], String[%s]", line, file, str);` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do with [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). The following command dumps Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) for the file `test.c` to the file `out`:

```
clang -cc1 -ast-dump test.c > out
```

Looking at the AST in the generated file you can easily find the information you need:

```
(StringLiteral 0x1376cd8 <line:12:9, line:13:13> 'char [11]' lvalue "Helloworld")))
```

Clang gives start of the first token of the string (line:12:9), start of the last token of the string (line:13:13) and the full string ("Helloworld").

You can either parse the AST dump or use Clang API to get the same information. If this is not a one time task, I'd go for API since the AST dump format is more likely to change in the future.

All this of course make sense only if you have a reason not to print the string in pLog itself.

Comment: Thanks!!. This is just a dummy form of the actual code where I want to avoid sending the string over the socket interface. So by collecting line number and file name I want to regenerate the log on the destination.